# NodeJS process never ends when piping the stdin to a child process

Tags: node.js, pipe, child-process

I'm using `spawn` to create a child process and pipe data:

```
child process  |  parent process (main)
---------------------------------------
stdout      ----->       process.stdout
stderr      ----->       process.stderr
stdin       <-----        process.stdin
```

The problem is that when piping the `process.stdin` to the child process `stdin`, the main process is not ended when the child process is finished.

The code looks like this (not a really good example because `ps` does not use `stdin` data, I guess):

```
var Spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var ps = Spawn("ps");
process.stdin.pipe(ps.stdin);
ps.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ps.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

If I remove the `process.stdin.pipe(ps.stdin)` line, the main process is ended, but the `stdin` data is not piped anymore.

Why isn't the main process ended when the `ps` child process is ended? How can I solve this problem?

An ugly solution would be:

```
ps.on("close", process.exit.bind(process));
```

I don't like this, because I don't really want to force the main process to be closed, but I want to be closed *naturally* (e.g. having `setTimeout(function(){}, 1000)` you wait 1000ms and then the process ends).

Comment: Did you try `Spawn('ps', [], { stdio: 'inherit' });`?

Comment: @Amit Using `stdio:'inherit'` works but I want to be able to pass any stream there. So, I still need to pipe things.

Comment: Try `ps.on("close", function(){ process.stdin.end(); });`

Comment: @stdob-- The `close` callback is reached, but after calling `stdin.end` nothing changes... Just like without it (the main process is not closed).

Comment: Might be related: [bug](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9190)

Comment: Instead of pipe, you could also do along these lines: ps.stdout.on ('data', function (data) { console.log (data); } This should duplicate everything from ps's stdout on main's stdout. Do the same for stderr. Maybe this fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is a bug in Node or expected behavior, but there's a couple of workarounds, one of which may be suitable for you.

If your current process is supposed to die precisely when the child process dies, you can simply add a handler for `exit` like this:

```
const fail = err => { throw err }
ps.on("exit", (code, signal) => code !== null ? process.exit(code) : signal !== null ? process.kill(process.pid, signal) : fail("Impossible situation, child process neither exited nor was killed"))
```

This will just bypass our issues with the `stdin` stream sitting there holding everything up.

If you do need to do more things in the current process than just run this child process, this approach may not be acceptable. What you can instead do is `destroy` `process.stdin` precisely when you become aware that all the work the current process is supposed to do has been accomplished. For example, if all you wanted to run was `ps` after all, you could add:

```
ps.on("exit", (...) => {
  ...
  process.stdin.destroy()
})
```

and this will have the same effect. If there's more work you need to do after `ps` is dead, you can put the same thing in some other appropriate event handler.